# C# / .NET cloud storage provider auth dialog

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, storage, onedrive

As a personal experiment, I am currently trying to create my own Cloud Storage Provider in C# with the .NET framework.

I have had a look at the Microsoft documentation located at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

After following the steps I succeeded to make my own OneDrive-like storage provider appear in the side menu.

Of course users should be authenticated in order to access their own files. When I click the OneDrive folder, it automatically opens a Authentication/Sign-in popup (if the user isn't signed in already).

After looking for a few hours, I can't find out how to do this myself..

Can somebody explain how OneDrive does open this dialog instantly when I open the sync folder?

Thank you!